# How to get All users which have a certain Role in grails

Tags: grails, find

I want to retrieve all users which have a specific Role like "ROLE_USER".

Below are Domain Classes for User, Role and UserRole.

**User.groovy**

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
        String email
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

**Role.groovy**

```
class Role {

    String authority

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

**UserRole.groovy**

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        find 'from UserRole where user.id=:userId and role.id=:roleId',
            [userId: userId, roleId: roleId]
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRole(user, role)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

These Domain Classes are generated by **Spring Security** plugin.
I have added only email field for User class.

Here is my **UserController.groovy**

```
class UserController {

    def index = {
       }


    def list = {

        def role = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        println "role id "+role.id

        def users = User.findAll()         //Its giving me all Users regardless of Role
        println "total users "+users.size()
        for(user in users)
        {
            println "User "+user.username+" "+user.email
        }
        render (view: "listUsers", model:[users:users])

    }
}
```

In the list action I used `User.findAll()` but its giving me all user with all roles.
I want user list only from a certain role..

**EDIT**

Code to Assign Roles to newly created user

```
def username = params.username
def emailID = params.emailID
def password = params.password

def testUser = new User(username: username, enabled: true, password: password,email:emailID)
testUser.save(flush: true)
def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)
UserRole.create testUser, userRole, true
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
def users = User.findAll()
```

with

```
def users = UserRole.findAllByRole(role).user
```

and you should get all users with the required role.

**EDIT**

In your code sample you try to create a new Role for the User. Since a Role with the authority ROLE_USER already exists and authority has to be unique (see the 'constraints' part in your Role class) this new Role cannot be saved to the database. Because the Role you assign in `UserRole.create` doesn't exist in the database the UserRole is not saved either. You would have to assign the existing Role to the new User (e.g. with `Role.findByAuthority').

Creating the roles in Bootstrap.groovy is a good idea according to Spring Source because roles "are typically defined early in the life of the application and correspond to unchanging reference data. That makes BootStrap the ideal place to create them." ([Spring Source Blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/))

Comment: Nope !! I am still not getting anything

Comment: Are you sure the roles are properly assigned to the users? What is the output for `println UserRole.list().role.authority`?

Comment: I am getting this [ROLE_ADMIN] only...
Check my code which I updated now for assigning roles to new users

Comment: Does a Role with the authority ROLE_USER already exist when you create the test user (`Role.list().authority` to see the existing roles)? You'd have to use the existing role then: `UserRole.create testUser, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'), true`

Comment: I am newbie to grails.. Can you tell me where I need to create this ROLE_USER because I did it for ROLE_ADMIN and it worked so think that this is the way to create ROLE_USER

Comment: `Role.list().authority()` giving me this `[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]`

Comment: Its working.... I have create two Roles as ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER already in Bootstrap.groovy.. by using Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') it worked.
Thanks but I would like to know Is this right way to create roles?

Comment: Yes this is what Spring Source suggests (also see my edit). Further discussion on the shortcomings of these hardcoded roles and a solution using a combination of permissions and roles can be found here: http://springinpractice.com/2010/10/27/quick-tip-spring-security-role-based-authorization-and-permissions/

Comment: Isn't it `def users = UserRole.findAllByRole(role)*.user` (the *)?

Comment: The spread operator `*` is only necessary for methods, not for properties. `UserRole.findAllByRole(role).getUser()` would not work because of the missing spread operator.

Comment: @saywow They are not entirely the same, hence my last comment. `someCollection.getUser()` tries to execute `getUser()` of the collection, which in the above case would fail, while `someCollection.user` collects the `user` property of the collection's elements which is equivalent to using the spread operator: `someCollection*.getUser()`